# Why does the thin man want Josephus to leave his apartment

Tags: plot-explanation, metropolis

In *Metropolis* (1927), Joh Fredersen orders his bodyguard/spy, called only The Thin Man in the movie, to shadow his son, Freder. He tracks the boy to the apartment of Josaphat, Joh Fredersen's former assistant. Freder has just left, and the Thin Man offers Josaphat a significant bribe to leave for three hours. Josaphat is horrified by this suggestion and The Thin Man says that this is the order of Joh Fredersen, and forcibly ejects Josaphat from the apartment before leaving himself.

The intertitles:

Joh Fredersen orders The Thin Man, saying "Von heute an wünsche ich, über jeden Schritt meines Sohnes genau unterrichtet zu werden...." [As of today, I would like to be informed of every step my son takes.]

When bribing Josaphat to leave, The Thin Man says "Also, welchen Preis verlangen Sie dafür, dass Sie diese Wohnung heute Abend verlassen haben?"[So, what price are you demanding for leaving this residence tonight?]  He then flashes money.

When The Thin Man is explaining to Josphat why he needs to leave, he says "Dieser Mann wünscht nicht, dass sein Sohn Sie heute abend noch hier findet!" [This man  doesn't want his son to find you here tonight!].

Kicking Josaphat out, The Thin Man says "In drei Stunden hole ich Sie ab!" [In three hours time I will call for you.]

Why does The Thin Man want the apartment empty? Why is Josaphat horrified by this? The entire episode seems to come to nothing; does it advance the plot in any way?